# Promoting child theme to stand alone

Tags: child-theme, performance

I have developed a website using a fully fledged theme packed with tons of bloatware and custom functions/widgets I am not using. The package is slow, and 95% of CSS (1MB!!!!) and Javascript is never used by the child theme.
This is why I am thinking about unlinking the child theme from the parent and promote the child theme as a standalone theme.
However this requires "walking" through PHP code, scripts and CSS to verify what is being used before trimming.

What steps would you take, generally speaking, to achieve this?

Comment: This question is way too broad to answer.

Comment: That's why I have wrote "generally speaking". The answer could simply be a few options like "debug php", "debug javascript" use a tool to cleanup unused CSS. Too difficult? ;-)

Comment: I've done this many times; start with "view source" of rendered HTML and then work backward from that, building a new theme by pulling whatever css, php files and functions from the parent as needed.  I have not yet found a tool that will identify unreachable .css; that would be helpful.

Comment: Thank you CC for spending two cents on this. Use your comments as a solution and I will select it. As for the CSS you could use Firefox add on dust me selector for this https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/dust-me-selectors/. And thanks to Toscho that keeps downgrading my messages! Relax mate

Comment: C C's idea is similar to what I would suggest.  Take the markup you have and build your theme fresh from scratch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start with "view source" of rendered HTML and then work backward from that, building a new theme by pulling whatever css, php files and functions from the parent as needed.

(footnote - thank you for the pointer to the 'dust me' utility, I will check that out).